# How to test the prompt command?

Tags: testing, prompt, raku

```
my $x = prompt "Are you OK? ";
say $x ~~ 'y' ?? "Great!" !! "Bummer";

use Test;
```

What tests can a put in a t/ file?  How can it respond to the prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to do it directly(probably by capturing handles), so I leave that to others, but you can put your code in a script file and test it with [Test::Run](https://raku.land/zef:CIAvash/Test::Run) module:

```
# script.raku

my $x = prompt "Are you OK? ";
say $x ~~ 'y' ?? "Great!" !! "Bummer";
```

```
# script.t

use Test::Run:auth<zef:CIAvash>:ver<0.2.*> :runs_ok;

runs_ok :args«$*EXECUTABLE script.raku», :in<y>, :out(*.contains: 'Are you OK? Great!');
runs_ok :args«$*EXECUTABLE script.raku», :in<n>, :out(*.contains: 'Are you OK? Bummer');
```

Comment: Thanks CIAvash!  Test::Run is what I am looking for.